# How to upload a link of file in postman instead of downloading file in Django

Tags: python, django, postman

I created an API, that take xlsx as input file for post method and give me edited xlsx file.

**Problem is**:- File I got from link and I have to download the xlsx file every time and put in postman.

**What I want**:- directly put link in postman for input file

**Note:-** Everytime link contains only one xlsx file

I Looked for the solutions in documentations , but I can't find a thing, of How to put link for inpt file.

Comment: have you tried `params` in postman

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the link with a header or just do one thing create an environment variable in postman itself and try to create that variable updated after every hut of the API by getting a response from the other API.